# Changing key of Multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

This is my first array

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Elite
            [2] => Air-Con Bus
            [3] => Monday
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => KBZ
            [2] => Airplane
            [3] => Wednesday
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => Yoma
            [2] => Cruise
            [3] => Tuesday
        )
)
```

I want to be inner `array[0]` to the outer array key. Like the following array: Can I or not? Please suggest me.

```
Array(
     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Elite
            [2] => Air-Con Bus
            [3] => Monday
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => KBZ
            [2] => Airplane
            [3] => Wednesday
        )

    [5] => Array
        (            
            [0] => 5
            [1] => Yoma
            [2] => Cruise
            [3] => Tuesday
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $el) {
    $new_array[$el[0]] = $el;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I can do like that! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I'm really curious: Why isn't this trivial solution obvious? It pretty much comes from your description of the problem: use element[0] as the keys of a new array.

Answer (score 1):

one way:

```
foreach ($array as $a){
$new[$a[0]]=$a;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I can do like that! Thanks a lot! :)